# Why won't the formidable upload the file to the public folder?

Tags: next.js, formidable

I want to upload images into the public folder in the next application with formidable module, but I'm getting some error. The error message is this: `error - TypeError: req.on is not a function at IncomingForm.parse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:182:13) at readFile (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/route.js:42:10) at POST (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/route.js:52:11)`
I followed some youtube tutorials, but it was not with nextJS 13, maybe this is the problem, I also updated the formidable to v3, but didn't help.

Here is the frontend page code, where the user can upload the image to the public folder:

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('');
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState('');

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', selectedFile);
    const res = await axios.post('/api', formData);
    console.log(res);
  };
  return (
    <div className=''>
      <form>
        <label>
          <input
            type='file'
            hidden
            onChange={({ target }) => {
              if (target.files) {
                const file = target.files[0];
                setSelectedImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
                setSelectedFile(file);
              }
            }}
          />
          <div className='w-40 aspect-video rounded flex items-center justify-center border-2 border-dashed cursor-pointer'>
            {selectedImage ? <img src={selectedImage} alt='' /> : <span>Select Image</span>}
          </div>
        </label>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' onClick={submitHandler} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the backend code, the api route, where I send the post request:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import formidable from 'formidable';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs/promises';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const readFile = async (req, saveLocally) => {
  const options = {};
  if (saveLocally) {
    options.multiple = true;
    options.uploadDir = path.join(process.cwd(), '/public/images');
    options.filename = (name, ext, path, form) => {
      return Date.now().toString() + '_' + path.originalFilename;
    };
  }
  options.maxFileSize = 4000 * 1024 * 1024;
  const form = formidable(options);
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) console.log('error');
  });
};

export async function POST(req, res) {
  try {
    await fs.readdir(path.join(process.cwd() + '/public', '/images'));
  } catch (error) {
    await fs.mkdir(path.join(process.cwd() + '/public', '/images'));
  }
  await readFile(req, true);
  res.json({ done: 'ok' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res.json({ done: 'ok' });
```

is happening before the callback of form.parse.
Promisify and await it